# Getting error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure Occassionally

Tags: android, mysql, sql, cloud

I am using Cloud SQL in my android app,everything works fine but some times cloud sql doesn't respond. I am unable to access the database through app with the following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

And at the same time the database is accessible through Local MySQL Instance running in my PC.
Please Help

Comment: Not an answer but we never try to connect to database directly. The best way to connect to database is via an API instead of accessing directly. Other than performance issues, security wise it's very easy to decompile application and get database username and password.

Comment: Is it sometimes or all the time that your Cloud SQL will not connect.

Comment: @apesa sometimes only it is not getting connected and after few minutes or sometimes few hours it gets connected

Comment: @sharj can you please site an example how can that be done in case of cloud sql

Comment: @emergence Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android If you are using Google Cloud SQL - it may help to read: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/